# Issue with <div> tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's what I think is a really simple problem that I can't seem to figure out. I'm working on a friend's website and I used the [lightGallery](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/index.html) JQuery plugin to showcase a video or two, but here's the problem. The code goes something like...

```
<div class="blah"> 
    <div class="more">
        <div id="lightGallery">
            <a href="#" data-src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=youtubeurl">link to open up video through lightGallery.</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That code will work perfectly fine. I can even add in another video link right beside it and it'll be included in the plugin's video gallery. However, when I need to include it in another section of the webpage, further down, the 2nd link won't function at all. Like this.

```
<div class="blah"> 
    <div class="more">
        <div id="lightGallery">
            <a href="#" data-src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=youtubeurl">link to open up video through lightGallery.</a> 
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="blah2"> 
        <div class="more2">
            <a href="#" data-src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ndyoutubeurl">link to open up another video through lightGallery.</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think I know why, too. The link has to be under the

```
<div id="lightGallery">
```

tag. But those other /div tags relevant to the styling are interrupting it from stretching over both links. When I try to call lightGallery twice using another div id tag, the 2nd link still simply won't work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation to make something a lightGallery you do:

```
// Makes an element with the id "lightGallery" a light gallery
$("#lightGallery").lightGallery();
```

So obviously if you don't have it inside a light gallery `div` it is not going to work. So just make two light galleries:

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#lightGallery").lightGallery(); 
    $("#lightGallery2").lightGallery();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="blah"> 
    <div class="more">
        <div id="lightGallery">
            <a href="#" data-src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=youtubeurl">link to open up video through lightGallery.</a> 
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="blah2"> 
    <div class="more2">
         <div id="lightGallery2">
            <a href="#" data-src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ndyoutubeurl">link to open up another video through lightGallery.</a> 
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```